# При поиске товара через SearchView постоянно переходит на первый товар.Хотя в SearchView был выбран абсолютно другой товар

Tags: java, android-search-view

Пишу приложение для просмотра товаров.На странице с есть Gridview и SearchView. Проблема в том, что после того как я нашел нужный товар через SearchView при клике постоянно открывает описание первого товара.(Даже если я нашел 10 товар при переходе на него откроет первый товар и характеристики про него)Но я искал совсем другой.Информация про все товары лежит в массивах.Буду благодарен любой информации, литературе, или статье!!!

Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


    Context c;
    ArrayList<Tovar> elements;
    ArrayList<Tovar> filterList;
    CustomFilter filter;

    public Adapter (Context ctx,ArrayList<Tovar> elements)
    {
        this.c=ctx;
        this.elements=elements;
        this.filterList=elements;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return elements.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return elements.indexOf(getItem(pos));
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView iconImageView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
            holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.titleTextView.setText(elements.get(position).getName());
        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(elements.get(position).getImg());
        return convertView;
    }

   /* @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,null);
        }
        TextView nameTxt=convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        ImageView img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        nameTxt.setText(elements.get(pos).getName());
        img.setImageResource(elements.get(pos).getImg());


        return convertView;
    }*/




    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter == null)
        {
            filter = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }
    class CustomFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
            {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<Tovar> filters = new ArrayList<Tovar>();
                for(int  i = 0 ;i < filterList.size();i++)
                {
                    if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                    {
                        Tovar p = new Tovar(filterList.get(i).getName(),filterList.get(i).getImg());
                        filters.add(p);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filters.size();
                results.values = filters;
            }else
            {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            elements = (ArrayList<Tovar>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity с товарами

```
SearchView sv;
    GridView gv;
    ImageButton home;
    ImageButton contacts;


    //родентициди
    String rotnazva[] = {"Бродівіт", "Шторм®"};
    int rotimage[] = {R.drawable.brodivit, R.drawable.storm};
    int rotimage1[] = {R.drawable.brodivit1, R.drawable.storm1};

    String h1rotsleva[] = {"ПРЕПАРАТИВНА ФОРМА:", "ПРЕПАРАТИВНА ФОРМА:"};
    String h1rot[] = {"Розчин", "Воскові брикети"};
    String h2rotsleva[] = {"ДІЮЧА РЕЧОВИНА:", "ДІЮЧА РЕЧОВИНА:"};
    String h2rot[] = {"Бродіфакум 0,25", "0,005 % Флокумафен"};
    String h3rotsleva[] = {"МЕХАНІЗМ ДІЇ:", "МЕХАНІЗМ ДІЇ:"};
    String h3rot[] = {"Антикоагулянт другого покоління, що порушує механізм згортання крові та викликає підвищену схильність до кровотеч, що призводить до загибелі гризунів.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Спектр дії:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Чорні та сірі пацюки, водяні щури, хатні миші, полівки, піщанки тощо. Принади на основі концентрату БРОДІВІТ (з кінцевим вмістом бродіфакуму 0,005%) готують з використанням кормового наповнювача (очищене зерно, крупи, комбікорм тощо). Рекомендується додавати атрактантні (приваблюючі) речовини (рослинна олія 3%, цукор-пісок 1%, ванілін тощо). До 49 кг сухого зерна або іншого наповнювача додати 1 л препарату БРОДІВІТ. Принади у великих об’ємах доцільно виготовляти за допомогою механічного змішувача.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Забороняється використовувати препарат у концентрованій формі!\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Норми витрати принад:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "В закритих приміщеннях: 10-15 г на 1 м2, на сільськогосподарських угіддях: 1,5-2,5 кг принади на 1 га.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Ефективність дії:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Шкідники одержують летальну дозу під час одного поїдання. Масова загибель гризунів настає через 5-7 днів після поїдання приманки. Уповільнений розвиток симптомів отруєння запобігає виникненню у гризунів побоювання до споживання принади, захисні реакції не формуються.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "МАКСИМАЛЬНА КРАТНІСТЬ ОБРОБОК ЗА СЕЗОН — В ПЕРІОД НАЙБІЛЬШОЇ АКТИВНОСТІ ГРИЗУНІВ — НАВЕСНІ  ТА ВОСЕНИ.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Норми витрати принад: в закритих приміщеннях: 10-15 г на 1 м2, на сільськогосподарських угіддях: 1,5-2,5 кг принади на 1 га.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Особливостi застосування:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "При боротьбі з  мишоподібними гризунами, особливо полівками, приманки розкладають восени або навесні, в період дефіциту природної їжі для гризунів з розрахунку 15-20 г  в кожну нору та присипають вхід невеликою кількістю ґрунту, з інтервалом приблизно 10-15 м. Приманки поновлюють через 7-10 днів до повного знищення гризунів. Приготовлену принаду розкладають за допомогою совка, пінцета або рукою, захищеною гумовою рукавичкою. Не використовувати столовий посуд! Заборонено торкатися голими руками згідно умов безпеки і в зв’язку з можливим відлякуванням гризунів людським запахом. Припиняють розкладання принади, коли вона скрізь залишається недоторканою гризунами.",
            "Сильний антикоагулянтний родентицид ефективний проти всіх гризунів (криси, миші, піщанки, полівки та ін.)"};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zzrrodentycidy);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searView1);
        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this,this.getElements());
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        //gv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
                                      {
                                          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ZZRRodentycidyListData.class);
                                          //intent.putExtra("name",fruitNames[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("imagee",rotimage1[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("name22", rotnazva[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("harakt1", h1rot[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("harakt2", h2rot[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("harakt3", h3rot[i]);


                                          intent.putExtra("harakteristikaa1", h1rotsleva[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("harakteristikaa2", h2rotsleva[i]);
                                          intent.putExtra("harakteristikaa3", h3rotsleva[i]);


                                          startActivity(intent);



                                          /*if (position == 0) {
                                              //Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, MainActivity.class);
                                              //startActivity(intent);
                                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                              intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0970986877"));
                                              startActivity(intent);
                                          }
                                          if (position == 1) {

                                              Intent intent3 = new Intent(NasinnyaKykyrydza.this, MainActivity.class);
                                              startActivity(intent3);


                                          }*/
                                      }
                                  }
        );


        home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home);
        contacts = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.contacts);
        contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (ZZRRodentycidy.this, Contacts.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (ZZRRodentycidy.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    private ArrayList<Tovar> getElements()
    {
        ArrayList<Tovar> players = new ArrayList<Tovar>();
        Tovar p;

        for(int i = 0;i< rotnazva.length;i++)
        {
            p = new Tovar(rotnazva[i],rotimage[i]);
            players.add(p);
        }
        return players;
    }

}
```

Tovar

```
public class Tovar {
    private String name;
    private int img;


    public Tovar(String name, int img) {
        this.img = img;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

Страница с описанием товара

```
 TextView name22;
    ImageView imagee;
    TextView harakt1;
    TextView harakt2;
    TextView harakt3;



    TextView harakteristikaa1;
    TextView harakteristikaa2;
    TextView harakteristikaa3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zzrrodentycidy_list_data);
        name22 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imagee = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        harakt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView45);
        harakt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView315);
        harakt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView325);

        harakteristikaa1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView55);
        harakteristikaa2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView185);
        harakteristikaa3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView215);


        Intent intent = getIntent();


        name22.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name22"));
        imagee.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("imagee",0));
        harakt1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakt1"));
        harakt2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakt2"));
        harakt3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakt3"));

        harakteristikaa1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakteristikaa1"));
        harakteristikaa2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakteristikaa2"));
        harakteristikaa3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("harakteristikaa3"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После фильтрации у вас остаётся один элемент - соответственно он становится первым.

Либо вам нужно добавить карту соответствий отфильтрованных индексов к оригинальным, заполнять её в фильтре и в `onItemClick` брать индекс товара из этой карты. Тот ещё велосипед.

Решение получше: дополните класс товара полем, в которое запишите его позицию, в `onItemClick` берём товар из адаптера и берём из товара его оригинальную позицию:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Tovar tovar = (Tovar) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    int index = tovar.getPosition();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ZZRRodentycidyListData.class);
    intent.putExtra("imagee",rotimage1[index]);
    ...
```

---

```
private ArrayList<Tovar> getElements() {
    ArrayList<Tovar> players = new ArrayList<Tovar>();
    Tovar p;

    for(int i = 0;i< rotnazva.length;i++)
    {
        p = new Tovar(i, rotnazva[i],rotimage[i]); // добавлям оригинальную позицию
        players.add(p);
    }
    return players;
}
```

---

```
public class Tovar {
    private position;
    private String name;
    private int img;

    public Tovar(int pos, String name, int img) {
        this.position = pos;
        this.img = img;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
 ...
```

---

Или аналогично предыдущему, только добавить в класс товара все необходимые характеристики и заполнять интент из него вместо массивов. Потом можно реализовать в товаре `Pacelable` или `Serializable` и передавать в интенте сам товар целиком.